# How can I download maven dependencies using node.js?

Tags: node.js, maven, electron

I have a JSON file containing multiple maven dependencies:

```
{
    "name": "com.paulscode:libraryjavasound:20101123"
},
{
    "name": "com.paulscode:librarylwjglopenal:20100824"
},
{
    "name": "com.paulscode:soundsystem:20120107"
},
```

I'd like to load them and then launch a jar with these dependencies in the classpath. Currently I'm not sure how to do that.

Also, I plan on using electron, if that is of any importance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [node-java-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-java-maven).

> ```
> Add a java key to your package.json
> ```

```
{
    "java": {
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "groupId": "com.paulscode",
          "artifactId": "libraryjavasound",
          "version": "20101123"
        },
        {
          "groupId": "com.paulscode",
          "artifactId": "soundsystem",
          "version": "20120107"
        },
        {
          "groupId": "com.paulscode",
          "artifactId": "librarylwjglopenal",
          "version": "20100824"
        },

      ]
    }
  }
```

Further more details you can find on plugin docs.You can use [node-java](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java) with this for addition purpose.

Comment: i have to download them prgrammatically during the execution of my programm